# Broken `/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0` on MacOS, cannot run `brew`

Tags: macos, homebrew, ruby, rubygems

To start, I had these following annoying output when opening my terminal:

```
Ignoring bigdecimal-2.0.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 2.0.0
Ignoring jaro_winkler-1.5.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine jaro_winkler --version 1.5.4
```

Ran `/usr/bin/gem update --system`

Resulted in:

```
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching rubygems-update-3.2.11.gem
Successfully installed rubygems-update-3.2.11
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.2.11
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-update-3.2.11
Installing darkfish documentation for rubygems-update-3.2.11
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 181 seconds
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.2.11
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 0 seconds
Installing RubyGems 3.2.11
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/gordonpn/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/plugins/gem-wrappers_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- /Users/gordonpn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/gem-wrappers-1.4.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb (LoadError)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb
```

Stupidly modified the owner `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/*` and tried the above command again.

Now each time I run `brew`, it's broken with this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 17: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:31:in `<main>'
 16: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:31:in `require_relative'
 15: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
 14: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 13: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 12: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
 11: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 10: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  9: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  8: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  7: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  6: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  5: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `load_native_extensions'
  4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `each'
  3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `block in load_native_extensions'
  2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:62:in `try_load_c_extension'
  1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- concurrent/concurrent_ruby_ext (LoadError)
 28: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:31:in `<main>'
 27: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:31:in `require_relative'
 26: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
 25: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 24: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 23: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
 22: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 21: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 20: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
 19: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 18: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 17: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
 16: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `load_native_extensions'
 15: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `each'
 14: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `block in load_native_extensions'
 13: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:62:in `try_load_c_extension'
 12: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
 11: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:123:in `rescue in require'
 10: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:210:in `try_activate'
  9: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `find_by_path'
  8: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `stubs'
  7: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:972:in `dirs'
  6: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:424:in `path'
  5: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:380:in `paths'
  4: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:380:in `new'
  3: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/path_support.rb:34:in `initialize'
  2: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/path_support.rb:67:in `split_gem_path'
  1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/path_support.rb:75:in `default_path'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/defaults.rb:94:in `default_path': undefined local variable or method `user_home' for Gem:Module (NameError)
```

I tried reinstalling xcode command line tools as I thought that would restore the system ruby and rubygems to their defaults.

It seems like it's an issue with the Mac's system rubygems, but I'm not sure to be honest.

I tried going into `/usr/local/Homebrew` and `git reset --hard`, but that didn't help.

I haven't been able to figure out how to reinstall the default system rubygems. Maybe I can symlink the rubygems from rvm, but I'm not sure how to do that either.

**Update**:

OS version: Big Sur 11.2.1

`/usr/bin/gem` returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    11: from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:323:in `to_spec'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:303:in `to_specs'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:280:in `matching_specs'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:843:in `stubs_for'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:972:in `dirs'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:424:in `path'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:380:in `paths'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:380:in `new'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/path_support.rb:36:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/defaults.rb:23:in `default_spec_cache_dir': undefined method `user_home' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: What OS, specifically? There have been big changes to /folder (as opposed to ~/folder) access permissions since Mojave

Comment: Big Sur 11.2.1, I should have added that to the post. Will update! @Tetsujin

Comment: Hokay - the actual answer is beyond me (I'm not on Big Sur yet) but that explains the issue. You have no perms to /folder (nor can you gain them by any means, you have to route things differently)

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me (on Big Sur 11.2.2)

```
rm -rf ~/.gem
git -C $(brew --repo) clean -xdf
brew update-reset
```